# Create datetime picker in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i'm trying to create date picker like this in asp.net, but its throwing me error. I'm using MVC architecture to create.

Here is the code i'm using.  i'm getting error as:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property
>   or method

I need date to be selected and sit in the edittext.

```
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 450px" class="" height="40px">
                            <%= Html.TextBox(ViewControlNames.DateTime, "", new { maxlength = "40", id = ViewControlNames.DateTime, Class = "LongInputField" })%>
                    </td>
    </tr>

         <script>
             $(function () {
                 $("#CabDateTime").datepicker();
             });
        </script>

    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: add jquery ui js library too.

Comment: Please provide your script include

Comment: hi @Jai, i didn't get you, can u please tell me what i need to do?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward, what script you want?

Comment: @Naruto you have to explain as if you are using `.datepicker()` method which is only available if you include `jquery-ui.js` library after `jquery` library.

Comment: @Naruto added example using date time picker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have not included the necessary jQuery UI library.

Add these script tags inside your page AFTER jQuery:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themename/jquery-ui.custom.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
```

In this way you'll have the jQuery UI widgets bound to jQuery.

Ref: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

If you need a datetimepicker; you can use a widget plugin that extends datepicker functions by adding a time selection.

Project site: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Demo code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#timePicker').datetimepicker({
        controlType: 'select',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm ss'
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Ljt4T/1/

Comment: @Naruto it's a forbidden resource error on jsfiddle, I'll fix it ASAP, try it here http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: actually above answer worked well, i just added <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: but i have given u a +1, but ill consider the first one as my ans, it worked by a simple copy past. Your answer is also very useful but i need to see the link which u have provided, thanks lot

Answer (score 1):

Have you added?

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
```

See from your comments you don't seems to be have added libraries and api at top of the page plese check it like i posted here

And for the further documentation please check here http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Hi, thanks dholakiya, but how to get the time picker? i'm getting only date. what about time

Comment: For my infomation you will have to switch timepicker for this Please check this link http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/timepicker/